# Joining the definitions of entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

$\int \frac{Q_{rev}}{T} = \Delta(k_B\ln\Omega)=\Delta S$ 
Could anyone give some definite proof for this?

I was able to prove that the two definitions of change in entropy are equivalent for an isothermal process carried out on a gas (by quantizing space and then limiting the quantization to infinity), but my proof makes the absolute entropy of the gas infinite. If the process is not isothermal, the particle's velocities come into the picture and I don't know how to deal with that. I tried making various assumptions (quantizing time, etc), but it didn't work. I know that once I prove it for another process, it will be proven for any process carried out on ideal gases(as I can write any process as the combination of isothermal and another process).

Could someone please nudge me in the right direction/give a proof?

Comment: In what framework do you work? If you know define the temperature as $\frac{1}{T}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial U}$, then you can just solve the first law of thermodynamics $\delta Q=PV+dU(S,V)$ for $dS$.

Comment: @NickKidman I'm defining everything on the basis of (P,V,T). Then I define $\Delta S$ as $\int\frac{Q}{T}$, and try to prove that this is equal to change in %k_Bln\Omega$ . How does your approach merge these two definitions of entropy? It seems that you are only proving a general formula for entropy (I'm not sure, though)

Comment: In classical thermodynamics, there are only macroscopical quantities. For every $(P,V,T)$, there are many many microstates. The introduction of microstates only comes with statistical mechanics. In that framework the volume $\Omega(E,V)$ is a natural object in phase space and $S(E,V)=log(\Omega(E,V))$ is the definition of the entropy. You can now compute the derivative $dS$ (where $dE$, i.e. $dU$, is related to $\delta Q$ via first law of theremodynamics, if you will). Both $T$ and $P$ are abstractly defined in terms of derivatives, although $P$ is easy to motivate.

Comment: Yeah, but I want to calculate $\Omega$ as a function of P/V/T/U/whatever. Omega as a func of V is easy at a constant temperature, but when the temperature changes, the speegs of the molecules add to the microstates in a way which I don't know how to calculate.

Comment: I don't understand. So you're doing calculations within the framework of statistical mechanics after all? If you have a potential like $U$ or $S$, then you can compute the equation of state, and if you like you can express $V$ as function of, for example $T$.

Comment: @NickKidman I don't understand either :P. I'm not using any "framework" of statistical mechanics. I am trying to count the microstates using normal mathematics and mechanics. Yes, I know this is part of statistical mechanics, but I'm not borrowing any equations from it. 

If there is no way to prove this without using statistical mechanics, I'd like a proof that I(someone with no knowledge of statistical mechanics but enough proficiency in maths and mechanics) can understand. If you could direct me to a link that explains all this from scratch, that would be nice.

Comment: In classical thermodynamics you start with $U, Q, W, P, V, T, S, c, H, F, G,...$in about this order + three laws. There is also an equation of state $f(x,y)=0$, where $x$ and $y$ are two of the variables $P,T,V$. These are the free parameters and there are *no particles*. Realize that thermodynamics is much older than Boltzmann, who (literally) died proving his atomic theory. There is no idea of particles, trajectories, phase space or microstates in thermodynamics. In statistical mechanics on the other side you start out with $F=ma$, phase space, define $S(\Omega)$ and deduce everything else.

Comment: @NickKidman Not exactly. I'm starting with the kinetic theory of gases, assuming PV=nRT. Now, for isothermal process($V_1\to V_2$), I basically broke the volume into a grid of some cell width x. Now, taking the number of particles,$\binom{V_1/x^3}{nN_A}$ is the number of ways of putting these particles in the grid cells (and is equal to $\Omega_1$. I did the same thing for $V_2$. Now, taking $S=k_Bln\Omega$, and writing $\Delta S=\lim_{x\to 0}k_Bln\frac{\Omega_1}{\Omega_2}$, I got $\Delta S=nRTln\frac{V_2}{V_1}$, which checks out with classical thermodynamics.

Comment: I limited it to zero as volume is not quantized in the classical world.
In this proof, I neglected the velocities of the particles, as the temperatures and hence velocity distributions of the particles were the same (So both $\Omega$s would be increased by the same factor). I'd like a way of counting the number of microstates for a system of moving atoms, which takes into account their velocities. I have tried various ways of doing this, but the mathematics either becomes too complicated, or the answer comes to be incorrect (I've tried doing it for an adiabatic process and an isobaric process)

Comment: Ah okay, particles after all. The general counting of microstates of non-interacting particles (although I don't know if this is what you want, because as I said this is statistical mechanics and only considers the hamiltonian, not any a priori equation of state) leads to the [Sackur–Tetrode equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sackur%E2%80%93Tetrode_equation). If you do everything from scratch, [this problem, fourth paragraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_paradox) will be a little intricacy.

Comment: @NickKidman Aah. Nice trick involving the volume of phase space. So basically they used the same approach as my approach for isothermal except that they included momentum as a part of 'volume' and quantised that as well. I was doing a different approach involving rms velocity etc and trying to use combinatorics (just became too complicated a system). The maxwell distribution did not help, either...

Comment: Oh, by the way, won't the proof given on that page work only for a monoatomic gas? They have taken $U=\frac{p^2}{2m}$, which will only work for monoatomic gases. Of course, we can renormalize angular momentum as part of the momentum, but it will add extra degrees of freedom, and then writing U as the sum of three momentum components will not work(we will have to take four or five or more)

Comment: Well, yeah, [phase space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_space) is the space where you count microstates. That remark was part of my second comment some days ago, I thought you knew what I ment.

Comment: @NickKidman I knew that phase space was basically a coord system of all parameters, and usually consisted of position and momentum, but I didn't know its relation with statistical thermodynamics (I just learned that it *comes from* statistical mechanics). I had seen it used in a very different context. So I didn't fully understand your comment. :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $k_B \ln \Omega$ coincides with entropy $S$ defined in thermodynamics comes from microcanonical ensemble.

---

There are many resources out there on microcanonical ensemble, for example, [this](http://www.sfu.ca/~malcolmk/teaching/PHYS445/Section2.pdf). After you come to the conclusion that

$$\beta=\left( \frac{ \partial \ln \Omega }{ \partial U }\right)_{N,V}$$

fully characterizes thermal equilibrium, you know that it must be a function of thermodynamic temperature, and thermodynamic temperature alone, by virtue of zeroth law of thermodynamics. So $\beta=f(T)$.

Compare this to

$$\frac{1}{T}=\left( \frac{ \partial S }{ \partial U }\right)_{N,V}$$

and you get that S must be the function of $\ln \Omega$. The remaining question is the exact form of this function, and you already derive it from special cases.

Comment: Could you please provide a more detailed explanation? I'm not too familiar with the statistical half of thermodynamics. I want to try to prove it by counting microstates in a system given P,V,T. If this is not possible, do you have a link/etc to the proof?

Comment: By the way, S as a function of $\ln\Omega$ can be more easily proved from the multiplicativeness of probability and from the fact that S is extensive.
Not exactly the type of answer I was looking for, but it'll do. Nick Kidman gave a nice explanation above that clarified my main confusion.

Comment: @Manishearth: How do you prove S as a function of $\ln \Omega$ from the multiplicativeness of probability and from the fact that S is extensive?

Comment: If I mix two systems with $\Omega_1$, $\Omega_2$, the resultant $\Omega=\Omega_1\times\Omega_2$. But, Entropy is extensive, so $S=S_1+S_2$. If $S_r=f(\Omega_r)$, then $f(x)=k\ln x$ (only function which turns multiplication into addition), thus $S=k\ln\Omega$. We can later set the constant $k=k_B$.

Comment: @Manishearth: But you need to prove that S is indeed related to Ω, and not to any other quantities. U is also extensive, but you don't get $U=k_B \ln \Omega$.

Comment: Oh. That I sort of assumed =P. I thought that it was fundamental that entropy was related to randomness, and the rest (both classical and statistical) could be derived from that. So I thought that you were proving  $\int\frac{q_{rev}}{T}=S_{classical}=S_{statistical}=k_B\ln\Omega$ from your above approach (which you sort of did); but assuming $S=f(\Omega)$ (which you didn't;but I had been doing earlier). Sorry about that, I've never formally studied statistical thermodynamics, so I don't know the history and what is considered fundamental (more importantly, what *isn't*).